# App store submission support url

Tags: ios, iphone

I am going to submit my application in app store. They need three url.

That are all,

support url
privacy url
marketing url

From above urls which is mandatory and optional to the app store submission?

Comment: Support URL is mandatory

Comment: at submission time apple provide all info which option or witch mandatory you have to read first it provided all related info near TextFiled.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policies, not actual coding problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support url is mandatory. Other two urls are optional.

Comment: Unless you're submitting an app specifically as "made for kids" in which case, privacy policy is mandatory, too.